# Andoid app Sync failed Gradle sync issues start up failed

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, synchronization

Opened my app and ran into gradle sync problems. I am so sure that I didn't touch the gradle files.

[image: Screenshot]

This is what I am getting -

> **ERROR: startup failed:
>   build file 'C:\Users\Ibrahim\AndroidStudioProjects\Misnap\app\build.gradle': 1: unexpected char: 0x0 @ line 1, column 8.
>      � � � �     5 V �  1   2  3   �  �   �  �   �  �   �   �  �   �     %  * +   -
>             ^ 1 error**

I tried

1. Delete iml file and .idea directory - didnt work
2. I also did a clean and rebuild project - didnt work, infact the clean project is not showing anymore, just rebuild.

Comment: Try deleting the build folder. **Go to Project -> Build** delete this entire folder and restart studio this folder would be regenerated.

Comment: No build folder, just build.gradle file.!

Comment: Have you tried Invalidate caches and Restart?

Comment: Yes, I have. Didnt work

Comment: The final step, If this project is on some version control system like Git you can try cloning this entire project. Make sure you delete this project first and Import the same project from version control.

Comment: The project is not on Github. I am so worried because I have gone a bit far in this project and all of a sudden getting this strange error which is not of my doing at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205178/discussion-between-icantc-and-ibramazin).