# How to get back .gradle folder in Android Studio after deleting

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors

My gradle files is messed up and I cant seem to open Android Studio without errors everywhere.

I asked a question about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546272/andoid-app-sync-failed-gradle-sync-issues-start-up-failed) which I still haven't fixed.

I deleted my `.gradle` folder in **Users/name/.gradle**

I also deleted the gradle folder in **Users/name/AndroidStudioProjects/project/.gradle**

I was hoping after deleting the folders and restarting androidstudio, the folders will be generated automatically and  fresh files will be obtained.

I guess I was wrong, both folders weren't created and the problem still very much there.

I have gone a bit far in this project, somebody help before I go crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

1. From **Android Studio** > Select menu **File** > **Close Project**.
2. **Dialog** will appear after **Close Project** > Select **Import Project** > Select **Your App** > **OK**.

If the error still appears, do steps like this.

1. Copy the code below to your build.gradle (Module:App).
2. Change **"com.mycompany.myapp"** to your previous package name (look in your AndroidManifest.xml)
3. Change **compileSdkVersion**, **buildToolsVersion**, **minSdkVersion**. **targetSdkVersion** same as your previous program.
4. Add **dependencies** same as your previous program.

**build.gradle (Module:App)**

> ```
> apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
> android {
>     compileSdkVersion 29
>     buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
>     defaultConfig {
>         applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
>         minSdkVersion 22
>         targetSdkVersion 29
>         versionCode 1
>         versionName "1.0"
>         testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
>     }
>     buildTypes {
>         release {
>             minifyEnabled false
>             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> dependencies {
>     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
>
>     // YOUR DEPENDENCIES
> }
> ```

5. Copy the code below to your **build.gradle (Project:YourApp)**.

**build.gradle (Project:YouApp)**

> ```
> buildscript {
>     repositories {
>         google()
>         jcenter()
>
>     }
>     dependencies {
>         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
>     }
> }
>
> allprojects {
>     repositories {
>         google()
>         jcenter()
>
>     }
> }
>
> task clean(type: Delete) {
>     delete rootProject.buildDir
> }
> ```

6. Press **Sync** button.

Comment: Worked, new gradle folder was installed but the error still persist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59546272/andoid-app-sync-failed-gradle-sync-issues-start-up-failed

Comment: Create new project with same "package-name", save it in different folder. Then copy that new grandle to your error grandle. Add dependencies to your error grandle then sync again.

Comment: This is working. Thank You! But it seems some of my java files and xml files are also corrupted. I am having something like this in xml and java instead of the codes I wrote - "<component name="AndroidLayouts">
    <shared>
      <config />
    </shared>
  </component>......."

Comment: Create a new simple program, if build it successfully then you don't need to reinstall android studio. But if it fails (the same error appears) then you have to reinstall Android Studio.

To restore lost files, you can use applications such as getdataback.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to view those files in sublime code editor, for some reason it didn't display the codes  correcly in android studio ide, so I am left with copying and pasting each code from sublime text editor back to android studio..

Comment: you're welcome, there might be a problem with encoding after deleting the gradle file.